# add/remove class at same time in java script (php module)

Tags: php, javascript

i am developing a module in PHP and i need to add/remove class at the same time using event onclick in javascript. 
Please suggest.

Below is the code but it is not working,

```
jQuery("#cat-block-id").show();
 //jQuery("#product-block-id").hide();
jQuery(".fme_layered_attribute").click(function() {
    jQuery("#product-block-id").show();
//jQuery("#cat-block-id").show();
})
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you using a javascript library such as jquery or prototype?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with jquery :

```
$('.currentClass').removeClass('currentClass').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
$(myElement).click(function () {
    this.addClass("className1");
    // ...
    this.removeClass("className2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

If not, then I suggest to use jQuery, which is very easy to use.
If yes, then you can use this:

```
$(element).removeClass('currentClass').addClass('newClass');
```

Since jQuery supports that, you can chain functions.

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you can get the CSS classes and *split* them by a space (one or possibly multiple) resulting into an array. Then, you can just remove the desired value out of the array, insert the desired class to the array, and *join* that array with a space as *glue*.
Then set this string as the `class` attribute of an HTML element.